# How many words are there?

Tags: code-golf, natural-language

English is such an inefficient language. We've got enormous words when
there are plenty of two or three letter words we never used! As
computer scientists, every keystroke matters. We need to be more
efficient. Just think of how many words we could have had! In fact,
don't think about it, tell me.

Given a string (or list) of letters, I want you to output how many
words we could make using those letters. You must use every letter in the string exactly one time.

Words can't just be any old string of letters though, how would you
say "yffghtjrufhr"? To be a word, it has to satisfy the following
conditions:

- It must contain at least one vowel ('y' is always a vowel).
- There must be no more than 2 vowels in a row.
- There must be no more than 3 consonants in row.
- The combinations "ch", "sh", and "th" count as one consonant.
- "s" counts as neither a consonant nor vowel ("length" is just as
  valid as "lengths").

For example:

```
Input    -> Output
a        -> 1       (a)
b        -> 0
ab       -> 2       (ab, ba)
abbbb    -> 3       (babbb, bbabb, bbbab)
abbbbbbb -> 0
essss    -> 5       (essss, sesss, ssess, ssses, sssse)
abbbth   -> 46      (thabbb, thbabb, thbbab, bathbb, ...)
```

Obviously, since this challenge is all about character efficiency, I
think a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge is in order. Standard rules apply!

(For clarification, an 's' breaks any streaks of vowels or consonants. The word "abbbsbbb" is ok, since there are no more than 3 consonants in a row".)

Comment: A bit late now that it's submitted, but would this question have been better as a "is it a word"-style question instead of "count all words"?

Comment: You could probably post each one separately (as long as they aren't dupes)

Comment: [3 consonants in a row](http://downlode.org/Etext/nine_billion_names_of_god.html) surely you mean 2...? :P Nice challenge.

Comment: I actually found [46 words](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bdb38ea363a21e881c9ea325b0685602) for the last test case. Maybe I misunderstand some of the rules, so please tell me which of these words are not allowed.

Comment: @ThePirateBay You are right, thanks for bringing that up. When writing that test it completely slipped my mind that the 't' and 'h' could be separated. I just used combinatorics to calculate, and forgot that 'th' wasn't just one letter...

Comment: Augh this would be so elegant in Perl if only it had a permutation function built in. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python 3, 166 Bytes

```
import itertools as i,re;print(len([w for w in[re.sub('[cst]h','b',''.join(x))for x in set(i.permutations(input()))]if not re.search('[aeiouy]{3}|[^aeiouys]{4}',w)]))
```

Takes a string from input(). The string is passed to itertool's (built-in library) permutations function, in this case taking a string and returning tuples of unique combinations when wrapped in set(). ''.join() turns the tuples into strings again. Combinations 'th', 'ch', and 'sh' are replaced with an arbitrary consonant, 'b' using re's (regular expression, built-in library) sub function. Words (variable 'w' in the list comprehension) are are then filtered based on if they contain 4 or more consonants, or 3 or more vowels using re's search.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 275 bytes

```
a=>(a.match(/[^aeiouys]/g)||[])[L='length']<a[L]*.85|0&&[...Array(1<<(n=(a=[...a])[L])*--n/2)].map((_,b)=>a.slice().sort(_=>(b/=2)*2&1?1:-1).join``).filter((a,b,c)=>c.indexOf(a)==b&&/[aeiouy]/[t='test'](d=a.replace(/[cst]h/,1))&!/[aeiouy]{3}/[t](d)&!/[^aeiouys]{4}/[t](d))[L]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TVBdT8IwFH3fr6gJWVuytQ41MUJnfCfxB9TK7kaBkdktayGSwW@fHcTpfTm9p/fcj7OHI9iiLRsXm3qt@43oQaQE2Be4Yke4/ARd1oeTVXxLz2epqFwKXGmzdTusFiCXasqen873YSgZY29tCyeSLBbECAJioGCQKDqNY8NnVPnGDSGrKKciBWarstCEMlu3jqz84JyLGZ3OwuQ1eYkTyvZ1abKMsk1ZOd0SAlEeFV5asNKs9ff7hgAVIg9DLm@LKi6dwE5bhxVZC2CtbirwQ7gsrFM7HiWUhndjefdw8QpfeiXHa7vHX3rYvj9Ci0rTHBwSSAYIYcDRAPkNYEQf/55jpq2Pvw/vXaDmQVDUxtaVZlW9Jdf2V3cAiRRlkw4uKI7jFE264cpLdnOD4A@DKZ33Pw)